# test service call with success () , error () in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

This is one of the functions in my controller

```js
function sendMeetingInvitation(companyId, meetingId) {

  meetingService.sendInvitations(companyId, meetingId)
    .success(function() {
      $state.go('company.meeting.view', {}, {
        reload: true
      });
    })
    .error(function() {
      //more code for error handling
    });

}
```

Below is the test case I'm using to test when we call the `sendMeetingInvitation()`, whether it should invoke the to the `success()` block of the service call of `meetingService.sendInvitations`

```js
describe('EditMeetingCtrl.sendMeetingInvitation()', function() {
  var $rootScope, scope, $controller, $q, companyService, meetingService;



  var mockedHttpPromise = {
    success: function() {}
  };

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('MyApp'));


  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$httpBackend_, _companyService_, _meetingService_) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    companyService = _companyService_;
    meetingService = _meetingService_;
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _meetingService_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    createController = function() {
      return $controller('EditMeetingCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        meeting: {},
        meetingService: _meetingService_
      });
    };
    var controller = new createController();
  }));

  it("should should send invitations", function() {
    spyOn(meetingService, 'sendInvitations').and.returnValue(mockedHttpPromise);
    scope.sendMeetingInvitations(123456, 123456);
    expect(meetingService.sendInvitations).toHaveBeenCalledWith(123456, 123456);
  });


});
```

I get this error which is not really helpful .

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8) In EditMeetingCtrl EditMeetingCtrl.sendMeetingInvitation() should should send invitations FAILED
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (near '...})...')
```

What am I doing here wrong? I tried my `mockedHttpPromise`  to following . but same result

```js
var mockedHttpPromise = {
  success: function() {},
  error: function() {}
};
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, my success is working fine but its chain into .error is getting an undefined. I resolved this issue by not relying on success( ).error( ) in my controllers and switch to only using .then ( )

Comment: hi @Malik any luck? Please let me know I am also facing same problem. Changing the code to use then is not an option for me as the source is developed by some other team and can't be changed.

Answer (score 2):

The function sendInvitations expects to return a promise, so, what you need to do is to create a defer and return it, like this:

-First of all you need to inject $q: `$q = $injector.get('$q');`

-Create a defer: `deferred = $q.defer();`

Your function mockedHttpPromise, should look like:

```
function mockedHttpPromise() {
    deferred = $q.defer();
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

And inside your test:

```
  it("should should send invitations", function() {
    spyOn(meetingService, 'sendInvitations').and.returnValue(mockedHttpPromise);
    scope.sendMeetingInvitations(123456, 123456);
    deferred.resolve({});
    scope.$apply();
    expect(meetingService.sendInvitations).toHaveBeenCalledWith(123456, 123456);
  });
```

And to test error block, change `deferred.resolve` to `deferred.reject`